# --Electric Bike-- How to measure left percent of battery?

Tags: batteries

I intend to make a module to measure battery of the electric bike instead of using the bike's indicator.

Measured battery (VRLA) is 48V, 12Ah. As I know, the specifications of an battery are voltage(V), current(A) and capacity(Ah.)

I want to find out the basic knowledge about battery help to measure the quality, the left electric percent.

Comment: Agreed - this is a question about batteries and estimating their remaining energy levels, and is only tangentially related to bicycles.   I'd suggest you go search the SE sites for electrical engineering, and electronics to see if they already have this answered.

Comment: What type of batteries are used? Lead acid or Lithium ion?

Comment: If its 12V SLA the battery is "empty" when it hits 10.5 volts.  Any more drain than that leads to battery damage (BTDT)  so I'd expect this to be a lithium-derivative battery tech.   It's unlikely to be Nickel-Cadmium or Nickel-Metal-Hydride because they're old and uncommon now.

Comment: Examine the graphs describing the discharge for a particular load for the battery in question, from that you can measure one or more of those parameters and apply a function to make it somewhat linear and indicate battery life.  You can try to just use voltage but its likely not going to be linear and the bike will likely not function all the way down to zero it is likely a relatively small voltage range that covers fully charged to the thing wont move...

Comment: @JackB, as I mentioned on my post, it is valve-regulated lead-acid (VRLA).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is a lead-acid VRLA, then you basically only care about the voltage (ie. the voltage closely corresponds to the state of charge). Very often the voltages are printed on the battery or in the manual/datasheet.

For a "12V" battery the typical values are:

- don't discharge below 10.5V
- cycle use: charge up to 14.4V
- standby use: charge and keep at 13.8V

To get values for 48V just multiply them by 4.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. 
Yep for a "48V" battery, the typical values are:
don't discharge below 42 V
cycle use: charge up to 57.6V
standby use: charge and keep at 55.2V. 
Can you give me the documents including the info you mentioned above? I really need it to design measure circuit.